# Add data persistence to WCF Service

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, durable-services

I'm in charge of a WCF service. Our client has requested an override feature: If a call is resubmitted, allow the operation to proceed despite warnings. I need a way to persist data from recent calls so I can detect a resubmission. I thought making the service [durable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb675272(v=vs.90).aspx), part of WF3, would resolve the problem; however, my service uses .NET 4.5 which marks WF3 as obsolete. I've been trying to find the WF4 equivalent, but nothing's clicked for me. All the examples presume a workflow which I lack.

What is the best solution for my needs?

---

Edit:

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275926/wcf-data-persistence-between-sessions), a static variable should meet my needs, but I haven't been able to get one to persist between calls.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable did meet my needs.

I used a property to interact with my static variable, and in the getter I would remove some of the old data. For some reason, having that call in the getter prevented the static variable from persisting. I relocated the clean up code (incidentally I didn't need the property anymore), and the static variable persisted.